# List apps in the App Store that can support a given file type

Tags: ios, app-store, uidocumentinteraction

I am working on a app which needs to open/preview a file using `UIDocumentInteractionController`. One of the clients requirement is that, in case there is no installed app which can support a given file type, then the app should redirect the user to the App Store, displaying a list of apps which can open the file.

Is that possible? If yes, could you give me a step-by-step approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app store does not have any list of apps can open a given file type.

You will have to build the list yourself.